# kotlin 1.2.70 and Android Room is not compatible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

When I bumped up Kotlin version to `1.2.70`, my builds started failing with an error:

```
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.my.app.db.AppDatabase, unresolved supertypes: androidx.room.RoomDatabase
```

I tried cleaning cache (clean cache from AS menu, Invalidate cache & Restart, then `rm -rf` build folders in the project) but the error didn't go away.
Then I downgraded to previous kotlin version I had (`1.2.61`) and now it builds successfully.

My Room version: `2.0.0-rc01` (androidx)

Answer (score 0):

Add all Room dependencies in gradle

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0-alpha2'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-alpha2'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-alpha2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have latest library versions for rx and room and then compile it with kotlin 1.2.70

Comment: I have the latest Room version but what's RX have to do with it?

Comment: actually nothing you can always use it without rx, but i worked on room database using rxjava and i have experience the same issue it was library version related issue at that time which i resolved and it worked.

Comment: I don't think it's related to rxjava. Nevertheless, it's up to date.